# Is there anyway to compile a Nativescript project into a Swift/XCode Project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nativescript, tns

I'm creating a Native iOS app & some of the business logic is already in Nativescript project. Is there anyway I can compile the Nativescript source into an XCode project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you run `tns build ios` command you actually get a Xcode project in `platforms/ios` directory.